# why Transformer is changing the attribute order of the XML nodes/tags

Tags: java, xml, xslt

We are using `TransformerFactory` and `Transformer` to save XML file after deleting a specific node.

However in code generated new XML, it is sorting attributes alphabetically and we want our XML without any other unnecessary changes, we want to retain all attributes as it is.

Can someone help with code to retain XML structure?

Here is Sample Input XML we are trying to edit:

```
<employee EndDate="12/31/2025" empCode="8881" changeType="change" employeeNum="000" BeginDate="08/01/2014" employeeName="Jose Milton" departmentPrefix="ISEC" stateId="93">
```

here is Java code we are us to delete a node and save XML to another directory:

```
if (BeginDate.equals(EndDate)) { 
element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
}

String outPath = outFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + inputXml.getName();

String outFileName = outPath.replace(outPath.substring(126, 129), "555");

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result ne = new StreamResult(new File(outFileName)); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

After code run XML looks like below, code sorted all attributes alphabetically which we want to avoid:

```
<employee BeginDate="08/01/2014" changeType="change" departmentPrefix="ISEC" empCode="8881" employeeName="Jose Milton" employeeNum="800" EndDate="12/31/2025" stateId="93">
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that the attributes are reordered?

Comment: After updating XML, we have some other steps for which i need the rest of the XML in same form as before so i m curious to know that it can be done or not ?

Comment: From [the XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags): “Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.”  In other words, any code that relies on the order of attributes is broken.  It was never safe to assume the order of attributes.

Comment: I'm curious why the following processing steps need the attributes in the original order. Maybe therein lies the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone, code is working fine and even the functionalities are also good but i m curious to know, all the attributes orientation is changed after transformation, is there a way to retain the original order of XML as it is?

Answer (score 2):

In the XDM data model used by XSLT, the order of attributes is undefined. Many XML processors (including parsers, transformers, and serializers) do in fact retain attribute order, but they are under no obligation to do so. You might find you get results that are more aesthetically pleasing (though functionally equivalent) by switching to a different XSLT processor (you don't say which one you are using).

If getting the attributes in a particular order is necessary for your processing pipeline to work correctly, then there is something seriously wrong with one of the steps in the pipeline. No application should ever depend on attribute order.

Because human readability of XML is sometimes important, the Saxon serializer supports an option to control the order of attributes in the output (but not to retain the input order, since the XSLT processor doesn't necessarily know the input order).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why doesn't the XSLT processor know about the attribute input  order? Is it because of allowing different XML parser implementations against a given API? What if the XSLT processor did it's own parsing?

Comment: Both in terms of the theoretical architecture and in terms of practical implementations, the XML parser produces a tree conforming to the XDM data model, and the XSLT processor takes that tree as input; and XDM says that the order of attributes is undefined. Now in practice, many XML parsers do retain the attribute order. But the XSLT processor doesn't necessarily know that the tree was built using a parser that does so.